# How to convert this category_detail function-based view to a CBV (DetailView)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I have this function-based view doing what I need it to do - get the list of all Posts filed under s specific Category and reach that list by going to example.com/economics/ (where economics is the slug od that specific Category). There I would find the list of all my posts filed under Economics category and create links so I can click on them and go to a single post page.

Currently, my FBV looks like this:

```
def category_detail(request, category_detail_slug=None):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    #Show only published posts
    posts = Post.objects.filter(status__exact='1')
    if category_detail_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_detail_slug)
        posts = posts.filter(category=category)
    return render(request, 'blog/category/single.html', {'category_detail_slug': category_detail_slug,
                                                         'category': category,
                                                         'categories': categories,
                                                         'posts': posts})
```

I started creating my CBV like this:

```
class CategoryDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Category
    template_name = 'blog/category/single.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

I know I need to pass some context, but somehow this keeps failing me.

My URL for this is defined as such:

`path('<slug:category_detail_slug>/', views.CategoryDetailView.as_view(), name="single_category")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it in following way

```
class CategoryDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Category
    slug_url_kwarg = 'category_detail_slug'
    template_name = 'blog/category/single.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        posts = Post.objects.filter(status__exact='1')
        context['posts'] = posts.filter(category=category)
        return context
```

Comment: Thank you, we are getting somewhere with this! I made some adjustments - but now it returns all posts for me, but how do I make it to return only posts from that specific category?

When using category=category in your example, it says that is not defined. Maybe something can be done with filters? `
class CategoryDetailView(DetailView):
...

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['posts'] = Post.objects.filter(status__exact='1')
        return context`

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it - I need to return category as self.object so it all looks like this;

```
class CategoryDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Category
    slug_url_kwarg = 'category_detail_slug'
    template_name = 'blog/category/single.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        posts = Post.objects.filter(status__exact='1')
        category = self.object
        context['posts'] = posts.filter(category=category)
        return context
```

But you helped out a lot and I will mark your response as an answer!